# How to assert the properties of a class inside a mock function with jest

Tags: node.js, express, jestjs

I'm having issues with mocked functions that are passing a class as a parameter. For some reason, it doesn't seem to assert the content correctly

```js
// ErrorHandler.js
class ErrorHandler extends Error {
  constructor(status, reason) {
    super();
    this.status = status;
    this.reason = reason;
  }
}

export {
  ErrorHandler
}

// express file express.js
const method = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    throw new ErrorHandler(401, 'error')
    next()
  } catch (error) {
    next(error)
  }
}

// test file
it('should call the next method with the proper error', async () => {
 const request = {
   body: {}
 }
 const next = jest.fn()
 const response = mockResponse() // here it's just a simple mock
 await method(request, response, next)

 expect(next).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
  // here the problem is that it doesn't seem to assert the parameters
  // and this test is passing
  new ErrorHandler('random text')
 )
})
```

I tried mocking the ErrorHandler class but then It gives another error related that it can't compare the next method anymore

Comment: Is postLogin the same as method? Also toHaveBeenCalledTimes takes a *number*. Please give a proper [mre].

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes indeed it's the same, also I change it to "With"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that Jest is trying to compare two error objects and doesn't really know how. You can see this with a simple assertion:

```
expect(new ErrorHandler(404, 'not found')).not.toEqual(new ErrorHandler(401, 'unauthorized'))
```

with the result:

```
expect(received).not.toEqual(expected) // deep equality

Expected: not [Error]
```

You need to be more specific, e.g.:

```
expect(next).toHaveBeenCalled();
const [err] = next.mock.calls[0];
expect(err).toMatchObject({ status: 401, reason: 'error' });
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, indeed can't make that test with only one assertion. In the case of the next function I used:
```//example
expect(next).toHaveBeenCalledWith(new ErrorHandler)
```